# RSync files or Map Network Drive in Windows Server?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server-2008, backup, rsync

I have to create a backup plan, from my machine .155 to .156.

In .155 my files are in `C:/MySQLServer/backup` and should be copied daily to .156 at `I:/MySQLServer/backup`, so I was looking over the internet for some tool like `rsync` in `Linux`. But I also was thinking into `Map network drive` that has in both `Windows Server v6`.

So I'm wondering about the differences, the advantages and disadvantages between both.
Any suggestions or ideas ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think mapping a drive will do for you, you would still need something like rsync/xcopy/robocopy/etc to copy the data from one location to the other.

Comment: But if I map the drive, should do the same thing basically ? Adding the remote drive into my .155 server ?

Comment: yes - but it won't copy any data. Rsync is an application that will copy/mirror data. It won't "add" the remote drive. Think of mapping the drive like mounting a filesystem except the drive letter is the mount point.

Comment: Got it. You would only 'read' the files, not write into the remote drive right ?

Comment: No. you can write to the drive after you mount it (provided you have permissions). My point is just mapping a drive doesn't do anythign for you. You would still need to use a script/backup utility, batch file, rsync, application, or SOMETHING to copy the data from your .155 server to the mapped drive.

Comment: Oh no, sure, this I get it, I would use something like `Cobian Backup` .

Comment: The big drawback with a mapped drive, is a user generally needs to be logged in for that drive letter to be connected/mapped. A service/backup application running the background would probably not be able to see the mapped drive.

Comment: You're right, I have to find some software that run at service level that can do the copy of my files to the .156 daily then, better then depends on the mapping drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use rsync/Cygwin for windows? [Deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) has a package that will push both together.

There are other options you can do depending on if/what you have budget for and what problem you are actually trying to solve (ie: do you just want your backups off the server? Why not have MySQL backup directly to the remote server? do you need multiple copies of the backup? Is using an actual backup application feasible? etc)

edit:
If you are looking at Cobian backup, why are you mentioning rsync? Those would do the same things.

If all you want to do is copy data from one location to another and there isn't that much data, write a batch/powershell/vbscript to do the file copy using UNC paths and run it as a scheduled task. Just make sure the user account that it is set to run under has proper permissions to the local directory and the remote share. If you want logging, you can do that with robocopy or redirect the output of your file copy to a text file in your script. If you want to use a 3rd party tool like Cobian, you can run it as a service and still use UNC paths to the appropriate servers.

Comment: I don't want to MySQL do the backup job, 'cause is faster do it locally and the schedule some application as you suggest to do that.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that `Cobian Backup` can be used to copied the files remotely, great to know that, thank you! It's perfect 'cause I can schedule on it and run in service level.

Comment: It says so right on the page: "Cobian Backup is a multi-threaded program that can be used to schedule and backup your files and directories from their original location to other directories/drives in the same computer or other computer in your network."

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft cloned rsync in a tool named [robocopy](http://theos.in/windows-server/free-download-windows-xp-2003-robocopy-software/) and it supports permissions cloning and windows shares. please note that the command line is very different, check some [examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851678.aspx)

that said, i usually do a net use j: //server/share and do the rsync using it. usually i only want the data, but if needed, there is a small free tool that can copy the [permissions](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/)

Comment: I think that it's a disservice to call `robocopy` a clone of `rsync`. Sure, they're both powerful file copy tools, but that's really where the similarities end.